# Redmine 3.3.2, Redmine git hosting plugin

Tags: redmine, gitolite

I am trying to install the redmine Git Hosting plugin for redmine 3.3.2.
I have followed the steps at (http://redmine-git-hosting.io/get_started/) but when i try the 9th step, which is to login to the git, I get asked for a password. There is no password on the GIT user, and just entering a blank password also doesn't work...

I can confirm that there's no password on the user:

```
[root@RedmineZonderDocker2 ~]# passwd -S git
git NP 2018-12-16 0 99999 7 -1 (Empty password.)
```

The log of the plugin does state this:

```
2018-12-16 20:16:47 +0000 [INFO] Testing if Redmine user 'redmine' can sudo to Gitolite user 'git'...
2018-12-16 20:16:47 +0000 [INFO] OK!
2018-12-16 20:16:47 +0000 [ERROR] Error while getting Gitolite infos, check 
your SSH keys (path, permissions) or your Git user.
```

I clearly have no idea where the problem lays, and as you might notice, i'm quite new to all this. Any help would be appreciated.

If you need other config files or logs, please let me know and i'll gladly provide them.

Kind regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have completed all the settings described in [step 9](http://redmine-git-hosting.io/get_started/#step-9-finish-installation---configuration) and **restarting Redmine after changing said settings**, as some of them are put in cache.

The password is only asked if the SSH key is not found or not properly register. In both instances, double-check "[Gitolite - ssh troubleshooting and tips](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/sts.html)".

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, and the plugin is functional now.

Comment: What was the exact problem, by the way?

Comment: Well there were multiple problems. The ssh keys,and the whole git user were bugged so i remade those completely, and i had some problems with the sudoers file nog being complete and having the wrong rights. Which caused the 7th step, checking the install with ssh -i ssh_keys/redmine_gitolite_admin_id_rsa git@localhost info to fail, it asked for a password which it shouldn't